# Undefined Variable in Element View

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I am using cakephp 2.5, why am I getting an error while trying to echo the content of an Element in another view.

the error says

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: job [APP\View\Elements\latestjobs.ctp, line 9]

Answer (score 2):

some more information would be really nice (a code snipped for example)

anyways, the error is pretty clear: you can echo the element, but you are using a variable $job inside that element which isn't defined in it's scope

Here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#passing-variables-into-an-element is an explanation on how to pass variables to an element

Answer (score 1):

To pass a variable through an element, you must set a second parameter:

```
echo $this->element('element_name', array('job' => 'Developer'));
```

With the above code, if you echo the variable **$job** in the element **element_name**, you will get the output: **Developer**